# bullet proof method to convert dates in pandas / python

Tags: python, pandas, date, format

I'm working with a script that processes a lot of data from different sources and in different formats. Usually I'm looking at spreadsheets, be it Excel or CSV. Everything runs perfectly and it would do all my work if it wasn't for either people or software (Tableau, I'm looking at you) deciding to change the date format every couple of days with no logic behind it.

One of the steps I'm running is transforming the date column into a date object using:

```
df['date_valid'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ReportingPeriod'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Of course, the date column sometimes contains dates in m/d/Y format (who invented this non-sense anyway?) and that messes up the script. I know the to_datetime() function can be ran without the format parameter, but I don't see how that will get things right, since there's no way to know whether I mean 2 Mar 2020 or 3 Feb 2020 in a date like 3/2/2020.

Is there a convention in software that gives a bullet proof (or something close) method of working with dates so that small changes don't break the script?

Thank you

Comment: you can use the [date-parser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module from PyPI I've not used it but I've seen it used on github and it seems to do what you need on the tin.

Comment: Usually you can't do better than am educated guess: if the dates are sorted, you can hopefully see the format from the sequence of dates. If you have dates with d>12 you can usually assume that the other dates has the same format

Comment: and here's the problem: the data I'm working with is 7 days at a time. there will be a time when the dates will fit both formats. so I guess I will need some "heavy weight" solution that involves current dates, try/catch etc. ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but you can add `errors = 'ignore'` after you signal the format.

Answer (score 0):

there really is no way to distinguish the data for d/m/y to m/d/y where d is less than or equal to 12 unless you have a different way of knowing how the column is formatted.